# HTML5 IOS/Cordova Hybrid App Input Fields Issue

Tags: ios, html, ipad, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I have an HTML5 app and on an IOS device when the input fields have focus the virtual keyboard  comes up and pushes the app view up but when the virtual keyboard goes away it leaves the app in the same state and I can't figure out why. Please see below screen shots and let me know your thoughts on the issues has I have researched the issue and can't seem to find a solution.

[image: What app should look like.]

[image: Virtual Keyboard showing]

[image: Virtual Keyboard not showing again]

Comment: Have you tried using a meta viewport tag to set device width and height in the head of your HTML?

Comment: Yes, already have meta viewport set.